# Bubbles in one faucet in the downstairs bathroom and also toilet WC

Tags: plumbing

- I live in a two story house

Recently, I have been noticing that there are lot of small bubbles in my downstairs bathroom faucet. Take a look at the image below:

[image]

After 1 minute the bubbles clears up completely and the water becomes clear.

What is causing this issue in the downstairs faucet. None of the other bathrooms are facing the same issue. Recently I changed the fill valve and the fill pipe of the downstairs toilet but apart from that I did not do anything.

In the afternoon I turned off the main water supply and then turned on all the faucets. After 5-8 minutes I turned on the water supply and noticed that the water in the downstair bathroom has become little clear.

But now at night I get the same problem.

UPDATE:

OK! Sorry I am super wrong! This is happening in all bathrooms upstairs and downstairs. The cold water (only cold water) has lots of tiny bubbles.

Comment: Welcome and hello..When water was off then put back on, broke free and   things may have clogged screen at the sink..  Take off clean it up or replace ..

Comment: The bubbles are also in toilet when I flush and it refills. But only in that one toilet downstairs. Another thing I noticed is that the water is only cloudy when I turn on the faucet at full blast. If I don't turn on full blast then the water is not cloudy.

Comment: Are all the vales and shut offs in that bath room  open all the way?

Comment: At the sink does that happen when hot only on.  Trying to narrow down to cold water feed.

Comment: Happens for cold only.

Comment: I took out the screen from the faucet and cleaned it. Maybe I made it worse because now even if the cold water is not at full blast it still comes out cloudy. So maybe the problem is with the screen as you suggested.

Comment: 1/2 bath or full with tub or shower ?  does that happen there ?

Comment: just faucet and toilet. happens in both

Comment: OK! Sorry I am super wrong! This is happening in all bathrooms upstairs and downstairs. The cold water (only cold water) has lots of tiny bubbles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94187/discussion-between-azamsharp-and-robert-moody).